# How to set static IP address for wi-fi connection?

Tags: wi-fi, settings

How can I set manually the IP Address for wifi?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Hit the hard menu button on your phone and then choose <kbd>Settings</kbd>.
2. From there, browse to the Wireless controls section and then choose <kbd>Wi-Fi Settings</kbd>
3. Whilst in the Wi-Fi Settings section, push the hard menu button again and select <kbd>Advanced</kbd>.
4. Press <kbd>Use static IP</kbd> to put a check in the box and then enter the network settings as per your own network.

If you’re not sure what your settings are, and assuming you’re using Windows:

1. Open a command prompt by clicking <kbd>Start</kbd>, then <kbd>Run</kbd>
2. Type in `cmd` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Type the line `ipconfig -all` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the relevant details should be listed there.

Just make sure you use a different number for IP address on your phone than is shown on your PC!

Comment: A great app called WiFi Static that automatically switches between static and dynamic addressing dependent on the wireless network you connect to

Answer (score 5):

If you control the network, you may be able to configure your DHCP server to always assign the same IP for your phone's MAC address.   This has the advantage of working even if you (for example) do a factory reset of the phone, or otherwise revert the wifi settings.

My Linksys E2000 router supports this via a button labelled "DHCP Reservation" on the Basic setup screen, and any host-based DHCP server would allow this as well.

Comment: This is what I do, and is a better solution than setting the IP to static on your phone if you plan on connecting to more than one network.  If your router doesn't show connected devices, you can find your phone's MAC address at Settings->About Phone->Status and then scrolling down to "Wi-Fi MAC address" to enter it manually.

Comment: Thanks, this  (the MAC address - IP address link on the DHCP server) is also a a solution to my recent question: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/232197/why-im-unable-to-set-a-wifi-static-ip-address