# Why I'm unable to set a WIFI static IP address?

Tags: wi-fi, settings, wifi-hotspot, mac-address, ip-address

On my Android mobile phone (a recent Huawey MAR-LX1B), I would like to permanently set a static IP address on a specific WIFI LAN router connection.

> The reason is that, on an application backend server, I want to "identify" connecting devices (specific
> unique mobile devices). A simple way to identify clients, on the web application, is to use caller IP addresses (debatable, I admit).

On Android (version 10) I would be able to change the local IP address to `static`, setting an IP of my choice, but on my phone, when I fulfill configuration data in the WIFI advanced section, the `save` button is disabled.

Any idea?

> BTW, do you think maybe ste MAC address - IP address setting on the DHCP server, here suggested: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/15827/338630 could be a better
> approach (to identify clients assigning them static IP addresses)?

Comment: thx @beeshyams I read the forum thread I tried the workaround. I didn't work. BTW the MAC randomization link is broken. BuT I read [this](https://www.mist.com/get-to-know-mac-address-randomization-in-2020/#:~:text=MAC%20Randomization%20is%20not%20a,not%20associated%20to%20the%20network.)

Comment: Sorry for the broken link. Try this https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/wifi-mac-randomization